# Android Button setHeight() error

Tags: android, android-button

When I am trying to do: `button.setHeight(900)`

So the following error occurred:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setHeight(int)' on a null object reference  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2423)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2483)
>     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:153)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1349)
>     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5438)     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
>     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void android.widget.Button.setHeight(int)' on a null object
>   reference     at
>   com.codeduc.aayushman.apps.htmlviewerpro.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:100)
>     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6303)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)

Please tell how to fix it.

Comment: You need to include at least some code otherwise we won't be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Any component available in xml must be initialized in the respective activity file. Then only it is availablein the activity scope
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.assetname);  //Need to declare
then we can do as follows
button.setHeight(100)
or more logically we can have as follows
int buttonWidth = (int) (screenWidth / 3.0);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) button.getLayoutParams();
params.width = buttonWidth;
params.leftMargin = buttonWidth;
button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: Thanks, Priya Raj. it helped me!

Answer (score -1):

Your button variable is null, Try to intialise it by using findviewbyId

Comment: I have initialised it in onCreate method. Using findViewById

Comment: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setHeight(int)' on a null object reference." Its saying on a null objec refrence. which means button is empty. You might be initialising with different id from layout